# Meaning of "very" in "When he walks the very ground shakes"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In [Kung Fu Panda animation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0441773/) Mantis says about the panda: "When he walks the very ground shakes". What's the meaning of "very" here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jim said, the word means *actual*, but I think there's a bit more to it than that. I think this usage of the word *very* injects a sense of awe or wonder into the event.

I **wouldn't** use *very* in this way when describing an ordinary event; for example, I wouldn't say,

> *When he pushes, the very shopping cart rolls.*

but I might say that about a strongman and a locomotive:

> *When he pulled, the very train rolled!*

I've never seen the movie, but I get the sense that Mantis either fears the Panda, or else holds the Panda in very high regard.

Comment: At that point Mantis neither fears nor holds Panda in high regard, and certainly is not in awe of Panda, who is a new recruit (albeit designated Dragon Warrior) then.   Mantis merely means Panda is grossly obese.

Comment: @jwpat7: Funny ~ as I thought of possible meanings, I thought about Godzilla. So it _is_ just a size thing after all. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is used as an adjective meaning *actual*

[***very***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/very#Adjective) : True, real, actual

> When he walks the *actual* ground shakes.